# Powershell move directory and add extension

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a homework problem and I can't get to the end of it:
 
`Write a shell that has two folder names as parameters and moves the second
folder as subfolder of the first one and adds '.unu' to all filenames in
that second folder.`

This is what I wrote but it doesn't work:

```
gci D:\powershell\dir2 | foreach-object{ ren -new ($_.Name + ".unu")} 

Copy-Item -Recurse D:\powershell\dir2.unu D:\powershell\dir2

Remove-Item -Recurse D:\powershell\dir2.unu
```

also you can see I made in `D:\powershell` 2 folders and I want to move `dir2` in `dir1`

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using pipeline here...:

```
Move-Item dir3 .\dir1\ -PassThru | Get-ChildItem | 
    where { ! $_.PsIsContainer } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + ".unu" }
```

Move-item will take care of moving folder for you, with PassThru you will get new object to play if... Pipeing it to Get-ChildItem will return what's in it (may consider adding -recurse there...).
Where will filter out directories (you were asked to rename files only), and Rename-Item will bind all files, and rename them as requested.

And someone wanted to write a script for that..? :o